# IntentService doesn't want to start

Tags: android, intentservice

I want to start IntentService from an activity but didn't running. I have tried tested it by using toast or Log but still didn't give any reaction.

Is there i have gone wrong ?

This is my activity:

```
 public class backgroundApplication extends Activity
 {
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {     
 findViewById(R.id.cmdServiceIA).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent msgIntent = new Intent(backgroundApplication.this, Service2.class);
            startService(msgIntent);
        }
    });
```

This is my intentService :

```
public class Service extends IntentService{
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    mHandler.post(new DisplayToast(this, "Service Start!"));
}
public class DisplayToast implements Runnable {
    private final Context mContext;
    String mText;

    public DisplayToast(Context mContext, String text){
        this.mContext = mContext;
        mText = text;
    }

    public void run(){
        Toast.makeText(mContext, mText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you share your stack trace?

Comment: There is no error. Just nothing. 07-14 08:48:17.296  31476-31476/skripsi.ubm.studenttracking D/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN

Comment: did you declare in menifest file

Comment: Thx for remind me. That was absolutely the fault. But now come new error. Process: skripsi.ubm.studenttracking, PID: 26647
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.Handler.post(java.lang.Runnable)' on a null object reference
            at skripsi.ubm.studenttracking.Service2.onHandleIntent(Service2.java:148)

Comment: You need to initialize it: `mHandler = new Handler();`  Also, onHandleIntent() runs in a background Thread, so you'll need to use runOnUiThread() to show the Toast.